# Why should I tag my type with CustomEqualityAttribute?

Tags: .net, f#

I've defined my own class

```
type public Observation(?values) = 
    ...
```

which overrides `Object.Equals`

```
    override o1.Equals o2 = 
        let isEqual = ...
        isEqual
```

and further have written a unit test which uses the global operators `=` and `<>`. I've verified my overridden `Equals` is indeed being invoked.

So what's the point of tagging my class with `[<CustomEqualityAttribute>]`? If I don't add that attribute, am I setting myself up for a nasty bug later? Unfortunately the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340350.aspx) on this attribute does not say much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [value of CustomEquality and CustomComparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594719/value-of-customequality-and-customcomparison)

Answer (score 4):

One reason could be that adding `[<CustomEqualityAttribute>]` forces you to override `Object.Equals`.  Without the attribute, deleting the `Equals` method would change the run-time behaviour, whilst adding the attribute enforces the equality method and would cause a compile error if it is missing.

To confirm why you need `[<CustomEqualityAttribute>]`, I looked it up in the spec, which states

> CustomEquality
>
> § The type must have an explicit implementation of override
>   Equals(obj: obj)

Comment: I'm all for quoting the spec, but the fact that the spec is so terse just seems to beg the question IMO -- what is the advantage of both overriding Equals and requiring that Equals be overridden over just overriding Equals?

Answer (score 2):

The justification for `[<CustomEquality>]` attribute existence comes from the cases where you **MUST** use it, not from ones like yours where you **MAY**. A very simplistic example of the former would be

```
type Strange = Behavior of (int -> int)

let a = Behavior (fun x -> x + 1)
let b = Behavior (fun x -> x + 1)

a = b
b = b
```

Compiler will bark on any attempt to use `=` because anonymous function element of `Strange` simply does not support any equality constraint.

Your options with regard to equality upon `Strange` type values are:

- either *never ever check values of `Strange` type for equality*, no need to use any attribute for this default choice
- or choose to *have reference equality* by adding `[<ReferenceEquality>]` to the type declaration
- or choose to *have custom equality*, when you must be adding `[<CustomEquality; NoComparison>]` to the type declaration along with explicit overriding of `Equals`  and `GetHashCode` members, and/or implementing of `System.IEquatable<_>` or `System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable`

You can find an extended explanation of F# equality and comparison constraints in [this Don Syme's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f-1-9-7.aspx).